# Master-Detail relationship questions

Tags: apex, master-detail

I have 2 questions when it comes to master detail.

1. We all know the detail object inherits its sharing from the master. But what about CRUD and FLS? My guess is that those are still separate but I am not 100% sure.
2. My second question is if you have a master-Detail relationship, could you display a child related list on parent record? What about if it is a lookup relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Record Sharing and CRUD/FLS access are very different things. You are correct that the detail will inherit the sharing from the master. CRUD and FLS are controlled by Profiles and Permission Sets. See here: [**CRUD, FLS and Sharing**](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2010/11/crud-fls-and-sharing.html) for a brief descripton of each.
2. Yes, you can display a child (detail) related list on the parent (master) page layout. This does also apply to Lookup relationships.